# Auth0 Hooks are not fired after user registers an account with Google

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, auth0, google-oauth

Whenever the user creates an account via Google, a hook should be fired that seeds the user's required data. Unfortunately, somehow it isn't working.

It does work if the user creates an account locally, though.

[image]

I've tried using Auth0's default credentials and with my own... Unfortunately, that hasn't done any difference. This is the code:

```js
/**
@param {object} user - The user being created
@param {string} user.id - user id
@param {string} user.tenant - Auth0 tenant name
@param {string} user.username - user name
@param {string} user.email - email
@param {boolean} user.emailVerified - is e-mail verified?
@param {string} user.phoneNumber - phone number
@param {boolean} user.phoneNumberVerified - is phone number verified?
@param {object} user.user_metadata - user metadata
@param {object} user.app_metadata - application metadata
@param {object} context - Auth0 connection and other context info
@param {string} context.requestLanguage - language of the client agent
@param {object} context.connection - information about the Auth0 connection
@param {object} context.connection.id - connection id
@param {object} context.connection.name - connection name
@param {object} context.connection.tenant - connection tenant
@param {object} context.webtask - webtask context
@param {function} cb - function (error, response)
*/
const f = require("node-fetch");

module.exports = function(user, context, cb) {
  // Perform any asynchronous actions, e.g. send notification to Slack.

  const evt = {
    accountType: "INSTITUTION",
    user: user,
    email: user.email,
    tenant: {
      id: user.id,
      name: user.username
    },
    schoolYear: "2019-2020"
  };

  // The URL of the API Gateway from AWS.
  f("https://lambda-url.amazonaws.com/production", {
    method: "post",
    body: JSON.stringify(evt),
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
  });

  cb();
};
```

But nothing seems to run once the user registers for an account using Google.

### Edit:

@CodingMorrison:

Thank you very much for your reply! [I have recorded the requests within a HAR file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EWEniDR3c5PhwSYR_dCIHrLai8Okr0-p) and I have not seen any problems whatsoever in the console or in the JSON response inside the logs.

Here's a snapshot from the logs (I went ahead and created both: local Auth0 user and a Google user)
[image]

Here's the successful google-oauth2 response:

```
// This is the response from the 
{
  "date": "2019-12-14T12:55:54.457Z",
  "type": "ss",
  "connection": "google-oauth2",
  "connection_id": "suppressed-for-security",
  "client_id": "suppressed-for-security",
  "client_name": "Schon",
  "ip": "190.167.241.8",
  "user_agent": "Firefox 70.0.0 / Windows 10.0.0",
  "details": {
    "prompts": [
      {
        "name": "oauth2-authenticate",
        "initiatedAt": 1576328144356,
        "completedAt": 1576328154233,
        "connection": "google-oauth2",
        "connection_id": "suppressed-for-security",
        "strategy": "google-oauth2",
        "identity": "110542431425060054283",
        "stats": {
          "loginsCount": 1
        },
        "elapsedTime": 9877
      },
      {
        "name": "login",
        "flow": "login",
        "initiatedAt": 1576328102203,
        "completedAt": 1576328154236,
        "timers": {
          "rules": 199
        },
        "user_id": "google-oauth2|110542431425060054283",
        "user_name": "asilisferis@gmail.com",
        "elapsedTime": 52033
      }
    ],
    "initiatedAt": 1576328102201,
    "completedAt": 1576328154455,
    "elapsedTime": 52254,
    "session_id": "suppressed-for-security",
    "device_id": "suppressed-for-security"
  },
  "hostname": "myhost.auth0.com",
  "user_id": "google-oauth2|110542431425060054283",
  "user_name": "asilisferis@gmail.com",
  "strategy": "google-oauth2",
  "strategy_type": "social",
  "log_id": "90020191214125558476000978979202312832857904117618573442",
  "_id": "90020191214125558476000978979202312832857904117618573442",
  "isMobile": false,
  "description": "Successful signup"
}
```

Here's the successful signup response from locally managed users:

```
{
  "date": "2019-12-14T12:57:05.511Z",
  "type": "ss",
  "description": "Successful signup",
  "connection": "Username-Password-Authentication",
  "connection_id": "con_QTrYODDyXlXqr1mA",
  "client_id": "secret-id",
  "client_name": "Schon",
  "ip": "190.167.241.8",
  "user_agent": "Firefox 70.0.0 / Windows 10.0.0",
  "details": {
    "body": {
      "tenant": "dev-qm4937yq",
      "client_id": "secret-id",
      "connection": "Username-Password-Authentication",
      "email": "secret-email@hotmail.com",
      "password": "*****",
      "request_language": "en-US,en;q=0.5"
    },
    "query": {
      "method": "POST",
      "host": "login.auth0.com",
      "port": 443,
      "resource": "/lo/users/direct",
      "id": "t3kVcfcDYX_mQXeXxy35W--PVShKHO4x"
    },
    "device_id": "secret"
  },
  "user_id": "auth0|5df4dc213eb6c90eb98f8ec7",
  "user_name": "secret-email@hotmail.com",
  "strategy": "auth0",
  "strategy_type": "database",
  "log_id": "90020191214125711760002735738646670240721436289261371474",
  "_id": "90020191214125711760002735738646670240721436289261371474",
  "isMobile": false
}
```

Here's the HAR file:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EWEniDR3c5PhwSYR_dCIHrLai8Okr0-p

Comment: Just wanted to add that Auth0 now is phasing out the Rules, and now is including "Actions". Haven't tried them yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer in the Auth 0 community.

Here's the link:
https://community.auth0.com/t/post-registration-hook-not-firing-for-social-connection-user/6364/4

Comment from prashanT:

> Hooks only run for Database Connections, as outlined in the docs 87. You can use Rules instead - @adampmoore’s answer is a great example.

And here's @adampmoore's answer:

> My temp solution until Hooks are ready for prime time, is to use a rule instead and set a app_metadata value when it runs, detecting for that value each time, to know if a user signed up already.

```js
user.app_metadata = user.app_metadata || {};
  if (user.app_metadata.signedup) {
    return done(null,user,context);
  }
```

> And then in the callback fro your API, after your API has been successful:

```
user.app_metadata.signedup = true;
auth0.users.updateAppMetadata(user.user_id, user.app_metadata);
```

Answer (score 0):

I work on the Auth0 Community team and I am curious if you are seeing anything in the Auth0 Dashboard logs when this hook should be firing? Any errors? What if you do a HAR file capture? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm updating the post as I write this!

Comment: I have added the HAR file https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EWEniDR3c5PhwSYR_dCIHrLai8Okr0-p, and I have added the signup logs. It doesn't seem that there's any errors. AWS Lambda fires only when the User-Signup is received. It can be seen from the CloudWatch logs. I can include those if it works.